# leaflet vector layers - popuptemplate

Tags: dictionary, vector, gis, leaflet

I am attempting to use Leaflet with Leaflet Vector Layers (http://geojason.info/leaflet-vector-layers/) and ArcGIS Server. I've set up the popup template and I can view the features as expected. But, when I click on a feature to get information I receive an error: 'cannot read property 'y' of undefined.' Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  The code I use to create the layer in question is below:

```
lyrHospitals = new lvector.AGS({
    url: oHospitals.url + '/' + oHospitals.layerIds,
    fields: '*',
    //uniqueField: "onemap_prod.SDEADMIN.hls.OBJECTID",
    popupTemplate: function (properties) {
        return '<p>hello there</p>';
    },
    scaleRange: [10, 20],
    symbology: {
        type: 'single',
        vectorOptions: {
            icon: baseballIcon
        }
    },
    singlePopup: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just updated Leaflet Vector Layers to work with Leaflet v0.4.x. Can you try with the latest [Leaflet Vector Layers](http://geojason.info/leaflet-vector-layers/download/) and let me know if you're still having this issue?